# Are pickle files reproducible?

Tags: python, hash, pickle

I would like to hash some `pickle` files for verification but I wonder if Python's `pickle` always produces the same output for the same input, at least within a protocol version? I wonder if the OS makes a difference? Do you have any references?

Comment: There is some discussion about it here: https://numba.discourse.group/t/reproducibility-of-pickles/603

Comment: In general, the answer is no, because a custom `__getstate__` can return whatever, e.g. a random number.

Comment: Oh, I missed that one. Do you know a valid example, why someone would return a random number (meaning not reproducible) `__getstate__`?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that as of now, the pickle process is [not](https://numba.discourse.group/t/reproducibility-of-pickles/603) [always](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39383) [deterministic](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19742).

Also, this is not a mystery according to how pickle works internally, but you might find this behavior disturbing:

```
>>> class B:
...     pass
>>>
>>> b = B()
>>> b.x = 1
>>> b.y = 2
>>>
>>> c = B()
>>> c.y = 2
>>> c.x = 1
>>> hash(pickle.dumps(b))
5326405855805501882
>>> hash(pickle.dumps(c)) 
-2711706543463941149
```

For the record, it seems that there was an attempt at using pickle for [scientific reproducibility](https://pypi.org/project/reproducible/) purposes, but the project seems now abandoned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One could argue that the code maybe equivalent but not identical. What about identical code (without custom `__getstate__`?